# How to fix the error:Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cli-auth.heroku.com cli-auth.heroku.com:443

Tags: heroku

I failed to use the Heroku to publish my projects demo for learning in my home's pc when i use the command heroku login, which cannot make me login my heroku account and create condition,before this I have successfully using it in my office pc.

Both of the running environment are windows 10 and match with shadowsocks to avoid blocking by the China's Great Firewall.
Restarting,flush the Dns and the ways I find in the Internet didn't work well.

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cli-auth.heroku.com cli-auth.heroku.com:443

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the interface being shutdown and heroku was basically inaccessible through the network connection.